# Cloud Firestore subcollection syntax in Web version 9 API

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to learn Firestore Cloud 9 using a tutorial written for Web version 8.  I am stuck trying to refactor what appears to be a subcollection of some sort.

The Web 8 code looks like this:

```
const ref = firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('posts');
const query = ref.orderBy('createdAt');
const [querySnapshot] = useCollection(query);
```

My (failed) attempt looks something like this:

```
import { firestore, auth, serverTimestamp } from "@/lib/firebase";
import { collection, getDocs, orderBy, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useCollection } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";

const ref = collection(firestore, 'users');
const q = query(
    ref,
    where('username', '==', auth.currentUser.uid),
    orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
);
//const newPosts = (await getDocs(q)).docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
const [querySnapshot] = useCollection(q);
```

I can get the first collection without issue. However grabbing the subcollection (?) via the doc(ument) isn't something I can figure out. I've tried getDocs() (commented out, above) as well as getDoc() & .doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the v8 and before syntax:

```
const ref = firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('posts');
```

Will look like this in v9 and later:

```
const ref = collection(firestore, 'users', auth.currentUser.uid, 'posts');
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for this?

Comment: I don't know if there's any specific documentation for subcollections in the guides, I just know from the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#collection) that `collection` takes a variable number of path segments.